# How to remove master node from elasticsearch cluster on runtime without down time

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search cluster with 5 master nodes. I want to remove 3 master nodes. How can I do that.

I would like to make changes to the config file as well.

Please let me know the step by step procedure.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should never remove 3 master nodes if you have 5 (because then you'll have an even number, 2, and you can encounter the [split brain problem](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#split-brain)).

I think the safest option is to first reduce to 3, and then reduce to 1 if you really need to. To reduce to 3:

1. Pick one of the nodes you want to keep; update its `elasticsearch.yml` file to set `minimum_master_nodes`at 2
2. Restart that node
3. Wait for it to rejoin the cluster
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for the other two nodes you are keeping
5. Stop the nodes you're removing

If you need to then reduce to 1 node, update the `elasticsearch.yml` on the node you want to keep with `minimum_master_nodes` of 1, restart and wait for it to join the cluster, and then simply remove the other two.

You could also consider changing another node in your cluster (a client, data, or ingest node) to also serve as a master node -- that is, keep 2 master-only nodes, and update one of the other nodes to also serve as a master node.

Comment: sorry I want to remove the 2 nodes out of 5 masters, what will be the procedure

Comment: Also the minimum node already si discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

Comment: Ok, that could have been a problem when you had 5 nodes, but now that you want to keep just 3, it's fine. Just stop elasticsearch on the nodes you don't want anymore.

Comment: Also there is one cluster that have 11 masters and want to remove 7 masters. Someone told me i have to change this setting in elastic.ym file node.master: true to false. is it so

Comment: so there are two different clusters one with 5 master nodes( which i want to reduce to 3) and one with 11 master node( which i want to reduce to 4). so both have minimum_master_nodes as 2 and all have node.master true

Comment: If you want to reduce to 4, you should change the minimum_master_nodes to 3 instead of 2 on the nodes you plan to keep, restart them, and then remove (shut down) the nodes you don't want to keep. However, usually you don't gain a lot from 4 master nodes over 3 master nodes (since you still have the case where only one can die and your cluster keeps running).

Comment: is there any other change in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml like discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts where i have to remove the servers IP's that I am goin to remove

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response! Anyway, yes you're right, of course you should remove the ips from discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts. I think that's it though. Adding/removing nodes from the cluster isn't really a "big deal" -- it's part of normal cluster operation.